# How to add quick search box to our application?

Tags: android

How to add quick search box (QSB) to our application?

Answer (score 3):

Check [this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html) on more info about the QSB in android.

and add this to your activity in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: Xr: if i add this to my manifest and if i give a query in the QSB will it provide search results only from my application  or does it take external data also ...?

Comment: This will apply only to your application.

Comment: I added that but I do not see the search function